Fetching ATH for newly created SPL tokens
Is there a library or api where I can fecth the current ATH of a new SPL token that is being traded on raydium?

coingecko is my goto for crypto API's. Not all tokens launched will be available as soon as they are launched, though as one of the requirements for the price to be tracked by Coingecko is

a cryptocurrency must first be tradable on a cryptocurrency exchange tracked by CoinGecko

To fetch a coming using their API, you'll need to use the public API
ref: https://docs.coingecko.com/v3.0.1/reference/coins-id
// fetching ATH for ore.supply
async function fetchATH() {
    const BASE_URL = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/ore";

    const resp: any = await (await fetch(BASE_URL)).json();
    console.log(resp.market_data.ath);
}

fetchATH().then().catch(console.error);

The other best alternative would be using Birdeye API which comes with a price history endpoint you can use to track the price of a token
ref: https://docs.birdeye.so/docs/price-history
You can also use the jupiter API to check for token prices, but I don't this tracks the ATH you're looking for.
ref https://station.jup.ag/docs/apis/price-api
async function fetchATH() {
    const BASE_URL = "https://price.jup.ag/v6/price?ids=SOL";

    const resp: any = await (await fetch(BASE_URL)).json();
    console.log(resp);
}

fetchATH().then().catch(console.error);


Thanks for the response. Coingecko is not really suitable since most of the SPL tokens like memecoins are not listed. Also the birdeye endpoint doens't return any data. Example:
{
"data": {
"items": []
},
"success": true
}
